# How do I get past poisonous snails?

Tags: let-it-die

When I first encountered the snails that radiated a poison cloud, they weren't too bad, since they were easily avoidable. However, after floor 10, these poisonous snails have been showing up a *lot* more frequently, usually in very tight quarters, where I'm forced to just man up and run through the poison cloud, usually getting poisoned in the process.

Is there a better way to handle these snails? For instance, is there any equipment that gives me immunity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take a risk and run into the cloud and punch the snails. Apparently the mushrooms that sprout from their bodies give you poison immunity for a full 30 seconds.

**Thus, it looks like the best way to bypass these snails is to just run up to them and punch them.**

In case you get poisoned in the process, mashing the `x` button after being poisoned will cause you to vomit. When you vomit sparkles, it means you've been cured of poisoning. If you vomit blood, you're still poisoned.

Answer (score 5):

As you've found the mushrooms they drop are useful for passing their brethren but something I often bring is a fireworks launcher, you can lock on and both kill and cook them in one shot for a quick health pick-me-up.  If you'd rather have the mushroom then any ranged attack that isn't fire based will work equally well.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know a fire-based weapon like the Fireworks Launcher would cook them as well as kill them.

Comment: Yeah, as long as there is some part of it that is fire based I think any weapon will cook instead of "mushroom-ize" beasts.

Comment: @LottVanfield I actually did not know that either, I have mainly stayed away from the fireworks launcher.  But not anymore!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've always gotten away with just rushing in and picking up the snail. You have to stay in the poison cloud for a certain amount of time for it to poison you, and catching the snail keeps you from getting poisoned.

Just crouching, walking up, catching, and either nabbing or eating the snail keeps me poison-free.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the poison cloud only affects me when I'm not wearing a head armor piece. I walk up to them and stomp them to get the shrooms they produce.